# How to create page transitions in next.js13 app router?

Tags: events, hook, router, next.js13, app-router

According to [next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-events) and [this github discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41934) router events aren't exposed anymore in latest versions of next.js.
So somebody made a [package (nextjs13-router-events)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs13-router-events) to achieve it.

### Problem

The methods provided in this package only works on client components and the concept is based on [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41745#discussioncomment-3986452).

### Objective

I want to create custom page transitions for pages, how can it be done?